# Can I make a update pc version build game?(I use a Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

My company project is a PC game and I use unity.

But I have a problem. If I need a game script update,

Unity assetbulde isn't sent a c# script.

How can I update? If I need. Add script or fix script?

Please Help me!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's hard to include scripts in AssetBundles.

To update your game, I suggest you use another launcher/updater to do the version control.

If there is an updated version on server, download the game_data and replace the old one.